# New to Devops. What are some ways I can extract data from Kubernetes?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, devops

I'm learning containers and how they work and started learning Kubernetes. I was wondering if there is a way I can pull or extract data from a Kubernetes cluster? What I want to do is to pull data from a cluster and monitor the information that is coming from it. I googled some and came up with some clients that work on nodejs and just wanted to know if I'm heading in the right direction.

what I'm trying to do is pull data from a cluster and put it on a front end website for me to see. (Thinking of making a compare CPU usage of different clusters site)

the link in question: https://github.com/tenxcloud/node-kubernetes-client

Comment: What about using a monitoring tool? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/

Answer (score 1):

Look into heapster (https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) with InfluxDB and Grafana as backends. Grafana is great for the type of monitoring and comparison that you seem to be looking for. This is sometimes included. With AKS in Azure heapster is there out of the box, but InfluxDB and Grafana must be added. I *think* that the entire stack is present in Google's offering.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at this. Will I be able to use this to communicate with a K8 cluster first? I was thinking of a script that connects to the cluster that probably logs "Cluster connected" or something like that

Comment: I don't quite follow that, but if you mean "can I connect from the outside and log external connection metrics to the same place" then that is easy. Simply make your script log to InfluxDB and you can graph it along with the other measurements.